# Securing Firebase RTDB with multiple databases for chat app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am on the blaze plan and building a chat functionality in my app using Firebase realtime database.

I have 3 databases for now :

- Main instance that contains sharding information and users chats' info.
- The 2 other instances will contain the chats and messages.

The database structure for the main instance looks like this :

```json
{
  "shards" : {
    "shard1" : {
      "full" : false,
      "name" : "shard1",
      "num" : 1,
      "url" : "shard1Url"
    },
    "shard2" : {
      "full" : false,
      "name" : "shard2",
      "num" : 0,
      "url" : "shard2Url"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the data structure of one of the shard :

```json
{
"users" : {
    "user_id_1" : {
      "chat_id_1" : true
    },
    "user_id_2" : {
      "chat_id_1" : true
    }
  },
  "chats" : {
    "chat_id_1" : {
      "created" : true,
      "createdAt" : 1645888918717,
      "members" : {
        "user_id_1" : true,
        "user_id_2" : true
      },
      "name" : "",
      "uid" : "chat_id_1",
      "updatedAt" : 1645895862214
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "chat_id_1" : {
      "mess_id_1" : {
        "content" : "Hello",
        "chatID" : "chat_id_1",
        "createdAt" : 1645895862214,
        "senderID" : "user_id_1",
        "uid" : "mess_id_1"
      },
      "mess_id_2" : {
        "content" : "Bye",
        "chatID" : "chat_id_1",
        "createdAt" : 1645889441313,
        "senderID" : "user_id_2",
        "uid" : "mess_id_2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the following rules to apply :
**Reads** :

- A user can listen for changes under `/users/$user_id/` where `$user_id` is `auth.uid`
- A user can get all the chats from the above IDs when he is in the `member` map (under `/chats/$chat_id`)
- A user can read all the messages from a chat when he is a member (under `/messages/$chat_id`)

**Writes** :

- A user can create a chat if there is no data under the `chat_id` node
- A user can update a chat if he is a member under the `chat_id`
- A user can create a message if a `chat_id` exists and if he is a member under the `chat_id` and if the `senderID` matches the `auth.uid`
- A user can delete a message if he is the sender of the message (not sure i can do this with security rules but only client side)
- A user can add only an item like `{"$chat_id": true}` under any other user under `/users/$user_id/`

So far, here are my rules that are not working :
-> Main shard :

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "shards": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".indexOn": ["full"],
      "$shardName": {
        "num": {
          ".write": "auth.uid != null"
        },
        "$other": {
          ".write": false
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

-> For other shards :

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userID": {
        ".write": "auth.uid != null && !data.exists()",
        ".read": "auth.uid == $userID",
      }
    },
    "chats": {
      "$chat_id": {
        ".read": "data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.hasChild('members')) || data.child('members/'+auth.uid).exists()",  
      }
    },
    "messages": {
      "$chat_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('chats').child($chat_id).child('members').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".indexOn": ["createdAt"],
        "$mess_id": {
          ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('senderID').val() == auth.uid) || (data.exists() && data.child('senderID').val() == auth.uid)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT :

I have made many edit regarding the database structure.
I especially need help with `reads` rather than writes, as writes seem to be working fine now but i would like confirmation and / or changes if you see mistakes.

Comment: To me it feels this has too much info. Limit yourself to smallest use case(single rule maybe) and failure results. This helps us to answer quickly

Comment: I have submitted a case to Firebase support, they are helping me on this :)